# How can I transform an object of a given type to a record?

Tags: f#, type-providers

I get a IEnumerable of object from using a [`SqlCommandProvider`](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/). Those objects match my rows and columns. Lets called it B. In my program I created a type matching those columns too. Lets call this record A. How can I actually transform/cast/construct a record c of type A based on values from B?

```fs
type A = {k: int; c: string}

let a:A = { k = 1; c = "c" }
let b = {| k = 1; c = "c" |} // lets say that this one simulate the sql's object
let c:A = b

printfn "%A" a
printfn "%A" b
printfn "%A" c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XczBCoAgEATQu18xCB07dDU6@Cm6WEhhYnuJ6tvN7FSXWYbHzri1tCaXM@/RQWPAMSv4wD1IYePkw3QJsTiGUZUxl@wKlyNJ4qpoHzr/dr5I9dMKEcscjwGy0RLmW@23Us43)

I got an error of type mismatch:

> error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type    'A'    but here has type    '{|c : string ; k : int|}'

Full sample code with the provider:

```fs
type A = {k: int; c: string}

let toA c =
    (A)c // ???

do
    use cmd = new SqlCommandProvider<"
        SELECT k, c
        FROM Examples
    " , connectionString>(connectionString)

    cmd.Execute() |> Seq.map toA
```

sql table if it matters:

| k | c |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | a |
| 1 | b |

I read the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/anonymous-records) without finding a solution to my problem. Maybe it is a comprehension problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should be able to have `cmd.Execute()` return the target record right away. Have you tried that?

Comment: Just make it the expected type of `cmd.Execute()`'s result.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Do you mean `let r:seq<A> = cmd.Execute()`?

Comment: Well, yes, that's one way to do it. Or you could `cmd.Execute() : seq<A>`. Or you could have the type come from whoever consumes the result of this whole block.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I got a type mismatch

Comment: I'm not familiar with SqlCommandProvider, but maybe it's similar to how it's done in LINQ. Just a thought.

Comment: @aloisdg as it is type mismatch, what happens when you type ``let b = {| k = 1; c = "c" |}`` is defining anonymous record type hence ``{| |}`` braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A working solution is to construct a record from the object:

```
let toA c =
    {k = c.k; c = c.c }

cmd.Execute()
|> Seq.map toA
```